# How to pass values from client side html to server side in classic asp or vbscript?

Tags: ms-access, vbscript, asp-classic, server-side-scripting

I have a form in html and need to pass the values from the form to my backend which is vbscript/classic asp. So, what I need to do is to store these values in an array in my backend and after that pass these values in my MS-Access database, where it can be stored for further processing. I am new to all this, and plzz reply as soon as possible.

Thanks in advance. :)

---

Thanks for your replies.To be more specific:

There can be N (max 10) number of items, and corresponding to each item there will be fixed 8 number of fields (regarding item's model number, price, date of removal etc). So, what I have thought is, make an array corresponding to each of the 8 fields (like one corresponding to model number, one corresponding to price and so on). Thus, I will have 8 arrays. Now, collect these values to complete a request (I mean, collect model number,date, price etc corresponding to each item). And then mail this request. I have got the code for mailing and know how to store it in the data base but there are 2 problems :

1) Dont know how to collect values in the dataase in the arrays.(in classsic asp/vb)

2) how to generate a unique key to gather all the information corresponding to each item in a single array and store in MS-Access database.

Hope now I am much more clearer.

Thanks all in advance. :)

Comment: Could you post some of the code you've got so far? What you're essentially asking is that someone code up the _entire_ solution for you; that's not really how Stack Overflow works... :-/

Comment: By "store these values in an array in my backend" do you mean to say "store the values in a table"? Otherwise, your question is nonsensical.

Answer (score 1):

You pretty much described exactly how to do it, so it's hard to know what answer to give you.

Yes, you have a form, and you submit that to the server. The ASP framework will let you access the form variables, and store it to a database.

I'm 100% sure it's described exactly how to do this in the tutorial for your platform, vbscript/classic asp. I can't give you an exact code example as it's over 10 years since I worked with ASP now and I've forgotten the exact syntax, but a quick google search found this form to database tutorial for asp:

http://www.codefixer.com/tutorials/form_to_database.asp